# Why are the template parameters required when defining member functions of a class template outside of the class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++14

In the following code, why do I have to write `someClass<Item>::increment()`, instead of just `someClass::increment()`?

Shouldn't the compiler realize, by itself, that `someClass` is a template class that takes `<typename Item>`?

```
template <typename Item>
struct someClass {
    void increment();
    Item x;
};

template <typename Item>
void someClass<Item> :: increment() {
    x++;
}
```

Comment: `void someClass::increment()` could be a function from `someClass` namespace

Comment: You can legitimately create a specialised version: `template <typename Item> void someClass<std::vector<Item>> :: increment() ...`. It is not

Answer (score 2):

Since `someClass` is a template class, that depends on a parameter, methods and and attributes also depend on that template parameter:

```
template <typename Item>
void someClass<Item> :: increment() {
    x++;
}
```

For every different `Item` there is a different code body for `increment()`. Possibly, the layout of `someClass` depends on `Item`, making `x++` refer to a different location inside `this`.

In this particular example, `Item` is never used directly so the language could make it implicitly.  It could be argued that the code could be made slightly shorter. It is done with [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), which is much more difficult. It is a matter of opinion, in the rare cases when a couple of lines could be saved, whether it is worth while to complicate the language and add a surprise factor. At least with CTAD there are benefits. Many programmers will be surprised to find out that something that looks like a regular class is in fact a template class.

The C++ has already many surprises in it, so it can be argued that one more surprise is not a big deal. It all boils down to a matter of opinion, not some deep technical reason for requiring the explicit (and redundant) template parameter in this example. SO policy is against opinions and favors facts, so please do not go any deeper than that.

Comment: @BeeOnRope https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction Class Template Argument Deduction, or CTAD

Comment: Thank you, a Google search mostly turned up something about Alzheimer's.

Comment: @BeeOnRope added a link to CTAD in the answer, to make it clean

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the compiler realize, by itself, that `someClass` is a
>   template class that takes `<typename Item>`?

Not necessarily. Here's an example that n.m. mentioned in a comment: consider that `someClass` has a specialization:

```
// general template
template <typename Item>
struct someClass {
    void increment();
    Item x;
};

// specialization for std::vector<...> parameters
template <typename Item>
struct someClass<std::vector<Item>> {
    void increment();
    Item defaultItem;
};
```

Now, defining the `increment` function template looks like this:

```
// general
template <typename Item>
void someClass<Item>::increment() {
    x++;
}

// specialization
template <typename Item>
void someClass<std::vector<Item>>::increment() {
    defaultItem++;
}
```

As you can see, both definitions have the same `template <typename Item>`, but they differ at `someClass<...>`.

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the compiler realize, by itself, that `someClass` is a template class that takes `<typename Item>`?

When the time the compiler sees the `::`, it does not yet know what it is you're really *doing*. All it sees is what is to the left of that token. So it sees a template header, followed by a typename (`void`), followed by the name of a class template, followed by the scoping operator (`::`). That's it.

Templates are not really things that exist in C++; they are a compile-time mechanism for *creating* things: classes, functions, and variables in C++14. The template name names the template, but the name followed by its template parameters is what actually creates the thing the template is meant to create. `someClass` names a class template; `someClass<Item>` names a *class*, not a class template.

And the name of classes can be followed by `::`.

What you're basically asking for is for the compiler to look at the template header, see that the name you have given the template parameter(s?) is the same as the name given to the template parameters of the template `someClass`, and then automatically substitute that in. That's just not how C++ works. What you're asking for is not very different from expecting the compiler to fill in function parameters just because the name of a variable at the call site happens to coincide with the name of a parameter in the function being called.

Parameter names, whether function or template, *do not matter* in C++. They're just identifiers; they only matter within the scope of what declares those names. Function parameter names only matter within the function that is being defined. And template parameter names only matter within the scope of the template header in question.

Your class uses a different template header from your member definition. So the names just don't matter as far as C++ is concerned. It is perfectly valid to do this:

```
template <typename Foo>
void someClass<Foo>::increment() {
    x++;
}
```

What you want just isn't how C++ works. Yes, C++ has places where the full template name can be deduced based on the context in which it is used. But those are not based on mere parameter names; they're based on arguments passed at the call site.